# NetBeans Java Web Application Git Not Working/Connecting Properly

Tags: java, git, netbeans, web, repository

Kinda strange problem that when I create **Java Application** project and click on 'Right click on the project'->Versioning->Initialize Git Repository... and connect to my repository, it creates package and file under Source Packages folder. Also Committing and Pushing works.

But when I create **Java Web Application** project do the same, it does not create the package and file under Source Packages folder. And probably this is the problem why the Committing and Pushing is not working.

I am trying to commit and push files to repository, but it does not upload them.

Any ideas how to set up repository for Java Web Application project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found out that this is bug that NetBeans have not solved yet.